# What type does `n` in `const n = 1u;` have?

Tags: c++, c, types, constants, variable-declaration

[Edit: The declarations discussed below are invalid in C++ and modern C; they relied on the "implicit int" rule of C which was later removed. Herb Sutter discusses the change [in a reader Q&A](https://herbsutter.com/2015/04/16/reader-qa-why-was-implicit-int-removed/). Thanks to the commenters and user2079303 for pointing that out.]

I am wondering about the inference of const variable types in C++.

Our old compiler compiles the declaration `const n = 1;`. `n` will have the type `const int`, I assume. I would think that the `int` is not inferred from the type of the initializing expression (`1`) but is a simple grammar rule.

What then is the type of n in `const n = 1u;`? I would assume it is also `int`, but cannot find the rule in the C++17 standard draft (which makes me wonder whether it is in fact illegal but tolerated by a lenient compiler). Also of interest is whether there would be a difference to C, hence both tags.

Comment: `const n = 1` shouldn't compile in C++.

Comment: While C and C++ shares some common syntax, they are very different languages. Especially when it comes to semantics and details like you ask about.

Comment: `const n = 1;` is invalid in modern C as well.

Comment: @P.P. there was a time when it was valid C ?

Comment: @user463035818 In C89, C had "implicit int" rule which allowed it. But it's been removed since C99, for good reason.

Comment: If you *want* the type inferred, then you need to spell it out. `const auto n = 1u;` Otherwise you just have an ill-formed declaration.

Comment: @user463035818 C was once a very simple language, where types wans't needed everywhere if you just wanted `int`. For example you could declare function arguments without types, and it would default to `int`. I haven't seen `const n = 1` myself, but I'm fairly certain it was allowed once upon a "prehistoric" time.

Comment: @P.P. cute, reminds me of fortrans implicit types

Comment: "cannot find the rule in the C++17 standard draft (which makes me wonder whether it is in fact illegal but tolerated by a lenient compiler)" what tolerant C++17 compiler? What C++ compiler? It is illegal in C++ and I don't know of any C++ compiler that allows this.

Comment: if you have a compiler at hand that allow this, then you could find out the type via `decltype`

Comment: didn't downvote, but I was tempted to. In my case is because you present a syntax that's illegal in `C++` as if it were legal which suggests you didn't even try to compile it and see that it doesn't.

Comment: @bolov I said that I wondered whether it is legal after I could not find wording in the standard, but only in the 2nd paragraph. My excuse for thinking it is allowed was that our (old) compiler doesn't balk, and also some superficial similarity to `unsigned n = 1;`.

Comment: @bolov I edited the question after learning that it is not valid C++.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the type of `n` in `const n = 1u;`? I would assume it is also `int`

In C89/C90, the type is `int`. There was a rule that if type name was missing from a declaration, it was implicitly `int`. Since C99, that rule doesn't exist and the declaration is ill-formed.

In C++, since the first standard version, the declaration is ill-formed. If you want to deduce the type to be `unsigned int`, you can use `const auto n = 1u;`, since C++11. In C, `auto` does not have the meaning of automatic type deduction.

Implicit `int` in `unsigned` -> `unsigned int` and `short` -> `short int` and so on still exists in both languages.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of it being illegal in C++; our compiler from the late 1990s compiles it. (I did start to wonder after the standard did not mention the possibility.) Thanks also for the information of the C evolution. I was aware of the implicit int rule and it makes sense that this case is simply an application of it.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider "I wasn't aware of it being illegal in C++" and the post's "declarations discussed below are invalid in C++" contradict.  Recommend to roll-back the edit.  It looks like your edit belongs in a answer, not as an question update.

Comment: @chux Yeah, I was not sure how to handle that properly. The remark is in square brackets to indicate that it is not part of the original question. But the original question was stating something factually wrong, which I think should be corrected or at least marked as that *in the question*. I think that is an improvement to the question. One could, alternatively, simply delete the question, but I think it is something which others can come across.

Comment: @Aconcagua To clarify: Pre C++11 `auto` did not have the same meaning as Post C++11 `auto`. It did have the same meaning as `auto` in C (which that of a storage class). I don't think there was never any need to use `auto` explicitly in post standardization C, or pre C++11 because automatic storage duration is implicit.

Comment: @user2079303 *I* am quite well aware of - just thought as you mentioned C meaning anyway, you might have added pre-C++11 meaning to your answer for sake of completeness. Never mind...

Comment: @Aconcagua I assumed *you* were aware of it, but I found your comment ambiguous, so I clarified for others. The other meaning of `auto` is in my opinion outside the scope of my answer, and I prefer to keep it in the comment.